# How to execute rawquery inside onUpgrade method (sqflite)

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I've this code inside my `onUpgrade` method (with `sqflite` package).

```
FutureOr<void> _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if (oldVersion < 2) {
    db.execute(
        "ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD COLUMN expression TEXT;");

    var results = db.rawQuery("select * from bookmarks order by bookmark_position asc");

    results.forEach((row) {  //error on forEach statement
      db.execute(...specific query... involving parts of this row);
    });

  }
```

But, I've the error on `forEach` : "*Static method 'forEach' can't be accessed through an instance.*".

So how can I do that : executing a query inside the onMigrate then, for each row of my result, executing UPDATE sql for migrating some data.

**EDIT**

Here is the complete code of my class:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class Db {
  static const _dbName = 'db.db';
  static final _dbVersion = 1;

  Db._internal();
  static final Db instance = Db._internal();
  static Database _db;

  factory Db() {
    return instance;
  }

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;

    _db = await _initDatabase();
    return _db;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    String path =
    join((await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path, _dbName);
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: _dbVersion,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
      onUpgrade: _onUpgrade,
    );
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) {
    db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE bookmarks (
        bookmark_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        bookmark TEXT,
        bookmark_position INTEGER
      );''');
    db.execute(
        "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX bookmark_idx ON bookmarks(bookmark_position);");
  }

FutureOr<void> _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if (oldVersion < 2) {
    db.execute(
        "ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD COLUMN expression TEXT;");
    //migrate expression stored in "bookmark" into expression
    //then transform this expression into http://google...


    //I cannot put await before db.rawQuery...
    var results = db.rawQuery("select * from bookmarks order by bookmark_position asc"); 

    results.forEach((row) {
      //manipulating row here BUT PROBLEM
      //Static method 'forEach' can't be accessed through an instance.
    });

  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should await all database actions. forEach is not recommended as you cannot await.

Untested code solution (or hint to find a solution):

```
FutureOr<void> _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
  if (oldVersion < 2) {
    await db.execute(
        "ALTER TABLE bookmarks ADD COLUMN expression TEXT;");

    var results = await db.rawQuery("select * from bookmarks order by bookmark_position asc");

    for (var row in results) {
      await db.execute(...specific query... involving parts of this row);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot put await before db.rawQuery because I've another error : "The await expression can only be used in an async function." I've added the entire code of my class for a better comprehension.

Comment: Add async like I did

Comment: You also have the same issue in your _onCreate. Add async in the method signature and await to all method calls. The return value should be Future<void> and not FutureOr<void> too for both _onUpdate and _onCreate

Comment: These methos have been created automatically by the IDE (using bulb in the ide) with the return type (FutureOr)

Comment: Even if my solution woks too (see my answer), your solution is more concise and easier to read. So I've marked your answer as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @alextk is better but, in the context of function Android Studio has generated for me (FutureOr...), the solution below works:

I've used the `then` syntax because `rawQuery` return a `Future`:

```
FutureOr<void> _onUpgrade(Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
      final results = db.rawQuery("select * from bookmarks");
      results.then((value) => {
            value.forEach((row) {
              final title = row['bookmark'].toString().toLowerCase();
              if (!(title.startsWith('http://') ||
                  title.startsWith('https://'))) {
                final url =
                    'https://www.google.com/search?q=${Uri.encodeComponent(row['bookmark'])}';

                db.execute(
                    'update bookmarks set expression = ?, bookmark = ? where bookmark_id = ?',
                    [title, url, row['bookmark_id']]);
              }
            })
          });

    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry to say that this is definitely not correct. You are not awaiting the result of the last update so the behavor is unknown at this point. Basically a transaction is created during onCreate/onUpgrade so you should await every database action. As I said, you should forget about what Android Studio generates, add async to the method signature and don't use forEach but use a for loop and await the db.execute commands. Good luck!